# unlisted android process

Tags: android

Is there a way to craft a daemon process as to make it "unlistable" to a process viewer?

OR

is there a way to dynamically change a process name?

I'd like to design a security application without having to modify the firmware, if possible (yes I know about "security through obscurity"...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to craft a daemon process as to make it "unlistable" to a process viewer?

Not from the SDK -- perhaps via your own custom firmware.

> is there a way to dynamically change a process name?

Not from the SDK -- perhaps via your own custom firmware.

> I'd like to design a security
>   application without having to modify
>   the firmware, if possible (yes I know
>   about "security through
>   obscurity"...).

IMHO, hiding from the OS and users is something that malware does, not something that anti-malware does.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.